# Unable to update bug throw j2bugzilla

Tags: java, swing, bugzilla

Hi all,

I'm customizing the bugzilla throw j2bugzilla using java swing app.While i'm attempting to update the bug exception is coming.Below thing are the code and exception

`UpdateBug update = new UpdateBug(currentBug);
                con.executeMethod(update);`

```
com.j2bugzilla.base.BugzillaException: An unknown error was encountered
    at com.j2bugzilla.base.XmlExceptionHandler.handleFault(XmlExceptionHandler.java:56)
    at com.j2bugzilla.base.BugzillaConnector.executeMethod(BugzillaConnector.java:154)
    at bugzilla.ui.Bugzilla.updateBug(Bugzilla.java:351)
****
****
Caused by: org.apache.xmlrpc.common.XmlRpcExtensionException: Null values aren't supported, if isEnabledForExtensions() == false
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.common.TypeFactoryImpl.getSerializer(TypeFactoryImpl.java:118)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.serializer.MapSerializer.writeValue(MapSerializer.java:73)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.serializer.MapSerializer.writeEntry(MapSerializer.java:67)
```

It was cleared after update the jar file from bugzilla 2.0 to bugzilla 2.1.1 which is supportive to xmlrpc-common-3.1.3.Thanks

Comment: Are any of the values in the Bug null which should not be? Can you provide more details?

Comment: In my proj i'm using xmlrpc-client and common -3.1.3 version.for this version we have to use updated bugzilla jar 2.1.1 not below version else even though we provide all bug values also it throws exception.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, it sounds like you ran afoul of a known bug which was fixed in the 2.x line -- see [the tracker](http://j2bugzilla.com/tracker/show_bug.cgi?id=7) for details. That being said, is there a real question here? Upgrading seems to have fixed it for you, as expected.